# JSpinner in Double format validation

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a JFrame witch act as user input form, It contains many fields of type JSpinner with Double format.

Ex:

```
 Double current = 0.0;
 Double min = (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 Double max = (double) Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 Double step = 0.1;

 JSpinner mySpinnerExample = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(current, min, max, step));
```

When  mySpinnerExample is empty (with default value 0) and the user clicks on O.K Button, I got this error.

Her is the full StackTrace

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at VIEW.ProduitUi.getFormData(ProduitUi.java:530)
    at CONTROLLER.ProduitController.getUiFormData(ProduitController.java:124)
    at CONTROLLER.ProduitController.createProduit(ProduitController.java:106)
    at VIEW.ProduitUi$2.actionPerformed(ProduitUi.java:284)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

How can i overcome this problem.

Comment: Have you tried with with Double.MIN_VALUE and Double.MAX_VALUE ?

Comment: Maybe you need to show more code - what does the ActionPerformed of your "OK" button do? I got it working without trouble, but I used jSpinner1.setModel() and inserted it as "post-init" code in my IDE (netbeans).

Comment: Consider posting a bit more of your stack trace too. (You can edit your question).

Comment: The exception almost certainly has nothing to do with the spinner but rather some method you are calling that you did not show us. The stack trace will tell you exactly what method call and line number throws the exception. We can not answer your question until you show us that.

Comment: I have update the post with the full stackTrace message

Comment: Show us the code where the exception is thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack trace indicates that your software is expecting a Double, but gets a BigDecimal.

Try replacing Double with double in the construction of the SpinnerNumberModel. I suspect that java used this constructor

```
SpinnerNumberModel(Number value, Comparable minimum, Comparable maximum, Number stepSize)
```

instead of this one

```
SpinnerNumberModel(double value, double minimum, double maximum, double stepSize)
```

(See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html))

So your code should be

```
double current = 0.0;
double min = (double) Integer.MIN_VALUE;
double max = (double) Integer.MAX_VALUE;
double step = 0.1;

JSpinner mySpinnerExample = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(current, min, max, step))
```

"Double" is a "Number", "BigDecimal" too, but "Double" isn't a "double", although both are somewhat related and easily assignable to each other.